# How to tell how many custom objects you can create?

Tags: licenses, servicecloud

- We are running the Enterprise Edition of Salesforce

  - We have a number of "Service Cloud Licenses".
  - Licenses are assigned via Salesforce Licenses with the Service Cloud feature being activated (to enable the console).

I have found this link: [Salesforce Feature and Edition Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_general.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Can anyone confirm that for "Service Cloud Licenses" using Enterprise we are still bound by the limits detailed in that link?

Essentially I want to create a lot of Custom Objects to develop on the Service Cloud but I just want to know where we stand with Org Limits.

Answer (score 4):

On Enterprise Edition you have up to 200 Custom Objects permitted with up to 500 fields per object.

With the Service Cloud licence this is not changed, but you need a Service Cloud licence for every user that will be using the Service Cloud console, however the custom objects can be used by any user with a Salesforce licence and permission to access the custom object.

If you are using a Customer Community the number of custom objects that you can surface to the Community (external) users is 10, however you can buy additional licences to increase this from Salesforce in blocks of 10 objects. See the [Commmunities licence documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.16#firstQueryMeta=%5Bobject%2520Object%5D) for the details.

Answer (score 2):

On reviewing the Product Comparison sheet, under the "platform feature of each edition" it states that "Custom Applications and Tabs" are unlimited for Enterprise Editions.  [Service Cloud Product Comparison](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/uk/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_ServiceCloud_EdCompare.pdf)

I am not 100% this is accurate...I can't find anything to state other wise.

[US version of the Document](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/salesforce-service-cloud-pricing-editions.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for providing the links.  Will continue looking - I "thought" I had imagined the limit was 10 somewhere but I can't find any evidence so yours (and the link I have in the question) is certainly enough info to go on.

Comment: Apps and Tabs are not Objects. Apps are collections of tabs and pages, and Tabs, while they may be attached to Objects, can also be attached to pages, canvas apps, web pages, and more. There's still Object limits.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that but they do like to confuse things with licenses.  Sounds like the OP had the right info.  It's determined by the edition: cheers.